# Was I wrong to flag this as NAA?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer, disputed-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433295/2263631) answer based on the NAA flag description:

> This was posted as an answer, **but it does not attempt to answer the question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

(emphasis mine)

However, it was disputed.

The question is specifically asking about how to run a piece of code only *once* on the first page load.

The linked answer only addresses the 'run onload' aspect of the question. It completely misses the aspect of running the code only once which is key to this quesiton.

Based on the above, was I wrong to flag it as NAA?

Comment: Moderators want you to vote on a post like this, they do not want to decide whether or not it answers the question.

Comment: @HansPassant so when would I use the flag?

Comment: @Script47 See the duplicate.

Comment: The dupe will point you in the right direction @Script47

Comment: You use the flag when it is obvious to a moderator that it does not answer the question.  You can flag "asdf" for example.

Comment: The dispute wasn't from moderators, it was from review https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19814349

Comment: @Servy & Makoto, Yep. thanks for the link the last part clarified it.

Comment: @Braiam what can be done about such reviews, if anything?

Comment: Get better critical reviewers that actually do what the guidance from the help center ask them to.

Comment: @Script47 What is there to do about the review?  They correctly identified that the post was an attempt to answer the question that was incorrectly flagged.  The post is clearly an attempt to answer the question.  What is there to do about reviewers that reviewed the post correctly and took the appropriate action?

Comment: @Servy no. You are right, going back to what the answer in the dupe, there is nothing wrong with the reviews. Apologies, my habit of assuming NAA means anything that doesn't directly answer the question kicked in. Old habits, I guess...

Comment: @Braiam - I fully agree with the reviewers in this case. This isn't just a link, and the answer provides suggestions for ways to approach the problem, so it does indeed appear to be an attempt at an answer. I would have declined this flag had I seen it.

Comment: @BradLarson I fully disagre with anyone that doesn't follow the help center: Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed.

Comment: @BradLarson does it? The OP asked: '*I am wondering if there is a way to execute a JavaScript function once only on the first ever page*' - There are two requirements present, the answer only catered for one.

Comment: @Braiam Just continue on from where you left off, the help center says, "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: -commentary on the question or other answers -asking another, different question -“thanks!” or “me too!” responses -exact duplicates of other answers -barely more than a link to an external site -not even a partial answer to the actual question" Note how there is not bullet for, "an answer that I don't like, or that I think is wrong" So *your own quote* makes it very clear that this answer doesn't merit deletion.

Comment: @Servy sorry but if the implication is that I flagged this question because '*I don't like it*' then you are mistaken. As for the part regarding thinking it is wrong, I still stand by that. It doesn't answer the question. However, as the answer in the dupe clarifies that NAA has a different meaning then sure, it is an answer. Maybe the flag name / description can be changed.

Comment: @Script47 You think it's a *wrong answer*, not that it *isn't an answer*.  And yet you flagged it as "not an answer", even though you think that it's an answer, just one that's wrong.  The flag is *very* specific about the meaning.  If you think that it's not a *useful* answer, then downvote it.  That's the proper tool for indicating that you think **an answer to the question** is wrong.

Comment: @Servy I think the confusion stems because: How can an answer be an answer if it isn't addressing the actual question? To clarify, if I was to answer a question which was tagged as C++, but my answer had completely irrelevant PHP code, technically any NAA flags that are used on my answer should be declined, right? I'm not looking to "argue", just a healthy discussion regarding the NAA flag usage.

Comment: @Script47 If it's a sincere attempt to answer the question, then it's not NAA.  Sometimes people don't realize what language a given question is expecting an answer in, or feel that an answer in a different language is still instructive enough that it will help people get their answer (at that point it's basically a pseudocode answer, which isn't inherently inappropriate, and certainly doesn't make it not an attempt to answer the question).  If you feel that the answer isn't useful as a result, there are tools for indicating you think *an answer* isn't useful.

Comment: If you think someone is just trolling and is intentionally posting unhelpful content just to rile people up, then NAA is not the correct tool for the job; use a custom moderator flag in such a situation and explain what you think is happening, as such a situation certainly requires moderator attention.

Comment: That answer literally leads with "It depends on what first page load means to you. It's subjective." You can disagree with that premise, but the fact remains that it alone demonstrates clear attention to the question, and an attempt at answering it.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess on this occasion we'd have to agree to disagree but I personally thought '*once only on the first ever page load*' was quite clear. But fair enough. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Script47: That's OK. I should add that when it comes to the NAA flag, the rule of thumb is to use it only for answers that look like edits, comments or questions that were incorrectly posted as answers. Posts that are "not an answer" by virtue of being things that aren't answers, if that makes sense. Like how an orange is not an apple. A PHP answer to a C++ question that doesn't make any acknowledgement of the nature of the question or even looks like it was posted by mistake *is* subject to deletion, but you're much more likely to get the expected outcome with a custom flag than with NAA.

Comment: @Servy "not even a **partial answer to the actual question**" It includes the reason why this answer should be removed in that very list! How can you ever say it shouldn't be removed even when the whole thing explicitly doesn't prohibit you from removing them? This answer is the equivalent to giving orange to someone that asks for apples, not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Braiam But it *is* an answer to the question.  It's an answer that you think is wrong, but it's *an answer to the question*.  Again, it doesn't say, "the answer is incorrect" in the list.  If you think it's wrong, that's fine, *you have a tool specifically designed for you to indicate that you think an answer is wrong*.  Go ahead and use it.  Just don't abuse other tools that exist to address entirely different problems than the technical accuracy of a post and get upset when you're told not to do that.  SO's policy on this has been made *very* clear *many* times.