# Why isn't this post that doesn't answer the question - but does provide interesting background - NAA?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

To me, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573073/325900) is a pretty clear cut NAA.

It's not a *bad* answer (as evidenced by its 31 upvotes) - it's well-written, and provides some excellent background that probably couldn't have been conveyed in a comment.

However, it objectively doesn't answer the question. The question is "How do I time the execution of a program?". This answer says "Using technique A (as advised by other answers) is potentially problematic". It doesn't do anything to suggest a better solution.

I raised a normal NAA flag, and it was declined with:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

So I flagged it for a mod's attention with the following comment:

> My NAA flag was declined, but this answer really doesn't address the OP's question. It provides some interesting background regarding System#nanoTime(), but the question is "How do I time the execution of a method". This is just a comment on the fact that a couple of answers have suggested using System#nanoTime(), not an answer to this question.

That flag was also declined for the same reason.

I realise that moderators aren't expected to be experts in all languages, so it's easy to understand that the point I'm making is fairly subtle, but I think I explained it about as clearly as possible in my second flag.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd say your right, it's not an answer, but why do you want it removed if it's helpful?

Comment: @George - very good point. I did have the idea that the better solution would be for me to edit it to make it an answer, with the additional explanation included, but that felt like a bit too big of an edit, and I don't know that I'd represent the OP correctly. Because it was an old answer I assumed the user wouldn't respond to a comment, but looking at his profile he does seem to still be active, so I've tried that instead.

Comment: There's nothing you need to do to "make it an answer", it already *is* an answer. Maybe not *the* answer, maybe not a *full* answer, maybe not the *best* answer; but *an* answer nonetheless.

Comment: Here we go... *again*.

Comment: @Script47 - sorry, clearly I've offended you somehow, but I'm not entirely sure what I did wrong

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave you've not offended me at all *and* you've not done anything wrong. I just think that SO (SE, whatever) should do more by way of trying to explain what NAA is on the actual flag page. It makes no sense why they don't just add the declination reason in the flag description: '*This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. **NAA should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer***'. So my frustration was / is not with you.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I doubt you've offended anyone, but this question is asked [a lot...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/265552?lq=1), likely because SO are not the best at describing what NAA really is

Comment: OK - I understand that, but the linked dupe and the phrase "technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" doesn't really address my question. I'm not saying it's wrong or that it's technically inaccurate, I'm saying that the question is "How do I X?" and the answer is "Don't do Y", where "Y" has only come up because it's something suggested by other answers. Therefore, surely this is a comment on those answers - perhaps with a link to a blog post or a self-answered question, if more space is required. From the image linked post, I see this answer as the orange.

Comment: BalusC has the correct answer, clearly the post you don't like was a response to it.  The hardware problem was fixed a long time ago, Core2 Duo in fact, pretty normal for programmers to share them getting burned before but not knowing that it is no longer a concern.  Well, it is 8 years old, a bit fresher in everybody's memory :)  Use your votes to adjust ranking.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave [believe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365644/where-did-i-go-wrong-with-this-naa-flag) [me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368528/was-i-wrong-to-flag-this-as-naa), [I](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355957/why-was-my-not-an-answer-naa-flag-declined) understand. However don't look at NAA as '*this does not answer the question*', look at it as: '*This answer should be a comment or is asking for clarification or some other NAA reason.*'.

Comment: The answer is clearly adjacent to the topic at hand. It's not talking about HTML or fixing a car. *Those* would be oranges.

Comment: @Script47, that is (more-or-less) how I look at it (and I agree with your point that the flag description has room for improvement). But I am saying that this post should be a comment! As Hans Passant has observed, it's a response to one (or more) other answers, not an answer in its own right. I take the point that it's adjacent to the topic, but only very tenuously. If it's not an orange it's certainly cider or an apple pie or something. But OK, I guess it's a bit more subjective than I originally saw it.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave just because an answer can exist as a comment, does not preclude the answer from being an answer. If the answer appears to be an attempt to answer a question conceivably asked on stack overflow, it is not NaA. The answer in question does indeed appear to be an attempt to answer a question conceivably asked on stack overflow. If you still want to delete it, you'll have to use delete votes.

Comment: Don't be fooled, other sites doesn't apply such absurd definition of NAA. If it doesn't answer the question to which is posted (ie. is not even wrong) on other sites these would be deleted without batting an eye.

Comment: @TinyGiant - "a question conceivably asked on stack overflow" - is that really what you mean? Even if that conceivable question is not the one that the answer is under? So, if I ask "How do I send a POST request in Spring" a valid answer could be "to make text bold in HTML use `<b>`"?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave yes. I know, I know it sounds absurd but that is how NAA works. The quicker people comprehend that the better. The answer in your example, though terrible, is still *an answer* (meaning it is isn't a question) therefore it fits, to counter it, you have to down-vote it but some people a hesitant you'll get penalised for down-voting answer (-1) and the counter to that is the rep is not important... but I digress.

Comment: @Yvette - I'm not sure how your dupe is related to my question. That's talking about something that makes sense as just a 'bad answer' - I'm inclined to say it's not really an answer, but can accept the argument made in that meta post. That's nothing like this answer though. _This_ answer is simply stating that the way some other answers have suggested is incorrect, without offering anything that actually addresses the question.

Comment: @Script47 - if the definition of an answer is simply "not a question", then almost nothing is NAA. It's clear that I'm the weak link here at understanding what that flag is for though, and I don't think I'm ever going to get it, so I'll just avoid using it in future, and downvote and comment instead, presumably only to get told I'm not being welcoming enough.

Comment: For clarity, I did downvote this answer, as well as flagging it.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave a distinction has to be made and as far as I can see there are three types of users when comes to NAA, there are those users who don't know how to use this flag, there are those users who don't agree with the usage of this flag in certain instances (you and arguably me) and there are those who are fine with it. I believe that most people make mistakes with NAA (and will continue) until they get used to it (or if the description is made clearer) and I wouldn't say stop using it, instead I'd say use it for extremely obvious cases.

Comment: I remember seeing a comment under the linked answer from the OP, why was it removed?

Comment: @Script47 - thanks for asking that, I didn't delete it and hadn't noticed that it was removed. Would be interesting to know the answer. As to your point on only using it for extremely obvious cases, I honestly thought I was - I'd seen the apples and oranges post before, and knew it was a controversial topic, but clearly I need to calibrate my 'obvious-ometer'.

Comment: The duplicate pretty clearly spells out *what to flag*: Thanking the posters, Asking a new question, Asking for clarifications, 'Bumping' the question, Links to an answer. Those are *common problems* on SO and they're *not answers.* That's what NAA covers. If it remotely tries to *answer the question*, as opposed to any of the aforementioned things, then there's no reason for a moderator or reviewer to remove it.

Comment: @deceze - your dupe does (I think that's the one titled 'When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?'), but I was saying that I don't see how the question Yvette linked to ('Why was this NAA flag declined') is a dupe as the answer its referring to is very different from the one I'm referring to. It doesn't make a difference, but seemed like an odd one of the many posts on the subject to link as a dupe, so I thought I'd ask why.

Comment: So there's two dupes now, one more applicable than the other. Ignore the not-so-relevant-one if it doesn't provide you any additional benefit.

Comment: @deceze - as I said, doesn't make a difference, just curious. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your tone, but you seem to be annoyed with me, and I'm honestly not sure why. I'm not attempting any personal attack, just trying to understand, which is what I thought Meta was for. I'll make one last try to explain my point - you say "if it remotely tries to _answer the question_", I'm saying it doesn't; all it tries to do is to address a perceived misunderstanding in _other answers_. If it were in the VLQ queue, I'd 'Recommend Deletion' with "This is commentary on another post, not an answer".

Comment: deceze is probably annoyed that this topic is discussed so many times, without clear resolution. I'm on the side that the resolution is to remove the absurdity that "attempt to answer a question conceivably asked" and match questions with answer in their logical path. Without the question, there would not be any answer.

Comment: I get where you’re coming from, but that is such a slippery slope that, in general, we don’t want to get into that business of picking the wheat from the chaff at that level of granularity. There are some *clear* Not-Even-Attempting-To-Answers. *Those* are NAA. Anything else that is not clearly NEATA (hey, new acronym! ) may be wrong or off the mark or otherwise not super useful, but we do not want to single-handedly have to make that judgement by *removing* it. If it’s not useful, downvote it and be on your merry way.

Comment: That makes practical sense, thanks. I suspect my lack of clarity on the mod tools doesn't help here. I've never found a good demo of what you guys see - is that a thing that exists? I'm thinking both how mod workflows work as well as some sort of idea of quantity of 'stuff'. In my example above from the VLQ queue, if I saw this answer, I'd open the question in a new tab, spend time understanding the context, and then either choose an action or skip if I couldn't decide. I guess that much time isn't a luxury that mods have, so you need a more clear-cut definition - is that accurate?

Comment: (equally likely is that I'm totally abusing the NAA delete reason in the VLQ queue)

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave It's not *just* about time. Mods aren't going to be adequately knowledgeable about *every* topic on this site to know what answers are in fact correct answers and what aren't.  Next, even if *they* wanted to make calls on the quality of posts, you probably don't want them to. What if they disagree with you on what answers are good, and they unilaterally delete your answer on the grounds that they think it's wrong? And yes, even if they did know enough about literally every programming topic to know what answers were good answers and what aren't, they don't have the time.

Comment: @Dave yes that is exactly what I meant, given that is exactly what I said. In order to determine whether or not any given answer does or does not apply to any given question requires domain knowledge, which is not used for evaluating NaA flags. If it requires domain knowledge to review, you should use delete votes.

Comment: @Braiam the idea that every moderator on Stack Overflow should be required to have adequate domain knowledge in  every domain represented in Stack Overflow such that they can unequivocally evaluate the topicality of every answer to every question is absurd.

Comment: @Braiam what frustrates me most about questions like this is that every time there is one, you take it upon yourself to give advice that is directly counter to the long established consensus and is just plain wrong. You're doing a disservice to everyone by doing that, and just serving to confuse people more.

Comment: @TinyGiant the idea that **you can evaluate Spanish or Japanese questions on es.SO or jp.SO is *very* absurd too**. So, why not everyone sticks with what they know well, like their own programming languages if they don't feel confident in evaluating post? At the end of the day, [it's demonstratively better for the quality of the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288121/213575)

Comment: @Braiam I dont understand, where does anyone say that Stack Overflow moderators should be moderating content on different sites? As for your suggestion, it seems you're suggesting that no mods review content that they dont have domain knowledge in, which would mean that most technologies represented on Stack Overflow would not qualify for moderation, as there are no moderators with domain knowledge in that subject. That seems like a _bad_ idea. What would be a better idea is not flagging stuff that requires domain knowledge to review and instead vote to delete, given that is what they are for.

Comment: I understand all of the above, but I still think (ironically) that you guys are answering a different question to the one I'm trying to ask! I get that mods don't have domain knowledge of every domain and that it would be impractical for them to have it, but I'm _not_ saying that the answer is "technically inaccurate" or "altogether wrong", what I'm saying is that just by reading it along with the question it's clear (based on plain English and no technical knowledge) that it doesn't _attempt_ to answer the question. It clearly addresses other answers, _not_ the question.

Comment: To try and illustrate my point, let's remove the programming-specific bits. Q: "How do you time a race? I'm not sure what device I should use to do this." A1: "Use a stopwatch. I prefer the Timer X3000". A2: "Use a stopwatch. The Clocky Y10 is best". A3: "Don't use the X3000, it doesn't work perfectly in certain situations and it has an unresolved bug". Surely it's obvious here that A3 is addressing A1, not the question? Or is it an answer because a discussion about the relative merits of the X3000 is a question that could _conceivably_ have been asked, even though it wasn't in this case?

Comment: @TinyGiant - I'm not sure what you mean by delete votes for answers - that's not something I have the option of, I guess it's a privilege I don't have yet, although I can't see it in the list of privileges that I can earn. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Aaaaand I'll repeat again that the scope of NAA is very specific and meant to target *common, undesired patterns*, like users posting "me too" or "thanks" *as answers*. Anything that falls outside that pretty narrow definition, we do not want  to have to moderate. Because again, it's a slippery slope. The answer in question here may or may not indeed more or less clearly fail to *answer* the topic. What about the next answer flagged as NAA which falls flat only 70%? What about the next one which gets it almost right but contains a bug? We. Do. Not. Moderate. On. Such. Issues.

Comment: Right. So no grey areas. Understood. However, it is trivially possible to moderate on issues of intent and tone to decide whether someone's unwelcoming in the perfectly clear and unambiguous English language? OK... I do get what you're saying, it just seems totally insane, but clearly it's a long-established consensus, so I'll accept it.

Comment: I would still love to hear why my comment on the post got deleted though, before the poster had the chance to see it.

Comment: You need 20k reputation to vote to delete answers. If you dont have that then your only option is to downvote and move on. It was built that way for a reason.

Comment: OK. Odd that you (with <20k rep) recommended to me (even lower rep) that I should use a feature that neither of us have access to, but fair enough, thanks for clarifying :)